# How do i make this HTML styled calculator work only using JS

Tags: javascript, html

I've been stuck on this assignment for a good while now.

Basically I have this rewritten HTML Code

```html
<input type="text" id="num1" value="" placeholder="input whole number" />
<input type="text" id="num2" value="" placeholder="input whole number" />

<br> <br>
Click on a operator:
<br>

<input type="button" id="add" class="operator" value="+" />
<input type="button" id="subtract" class="operator" value="-" />
<input type="button" id="multiply" class="operator" value="*" />
<input type="button" id="divide" class="operator" value="/" />

<p class="semig">Result is: <span id="resultat">???</span></p>
```

I'm only allowed to make the calculator work using JS no editing the HTML.

Normally I would write the function in JS but have the function being called in the HTML code.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Use `addEventListener()` to call the functions.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event#JavaScript

Comment: You can use addEventListener to assign js functions to individual html elements. There is no need to edit html code, this can be done in a separate is file.

Comment: Also be sure to convert the values from the inputs into numbers rather than strings before using them for math

Answer (score 2):

Consider a generic event handler:

```
function buttonClick(event) {
  alert("You clicked " + event.target.id);
}
```

The buttons have IDs, so you can attach event listeners to them.

```js
document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click", buttonClick, false);
// etc... for the other buttons
```

Even better, they have classes, so you can just look them up and attach event listeners:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("button.operator")).forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener("click", buttonClick, false);
});
```

An even more advanced option is to add the click handler on e.g. `document.body` and use event propagation/bubbling to see which was the actual element clicked.

Comment: Turns out it's rather difficult to add code snippets to a comment. Basically what I'm trying to say is that I can't for the life of me get a working function, and I was hoping you could provide a working example of a function that will add 2 numbers and display the result and walkthrough of the code, if you got the time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this code :

```js
 var addButton = document.getElementById("add");
 addButton.onclick = function() {
  calculate("+");
 }

 var subtractButton = document.getElementById("subtract");
 subtractButton.onclick = function() {
  calculate("-");
 }

 var multiplyButton = document.getElementById("multiply");
 multiplyButton.onclick = function() {
  calculate("*");
 }

 var divideButton = document.getElementById("divide");
 divideButton.onclick = function() {
  calculate("/");
 }

 function calculate(operation) {
   var num1 = document.getElementById("num1").value;
   var num2 = document.getElementById("num2").value;
   try {
     eval("var result = " + num1.toString() + operation + num2.toString());
     document.getElementById("resultat").innerHTML = result;
   }
   catch {
     alert("You must enter numbers in theses fills");
   }
 }
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<input type="text" id="num1" value="" placeholder="input whole number" />
<input type="text" id="num2" value="" placeholder="input whole number" />

<br> <br>
Click on a operator:
<br>

<input type="button" id="add" class="operator" value="+" />
<input type="button" id="subtract" class="operator" value="-" />
<input type="button" id="multiply" class="operator" value="*" />
<input type="button" id="divide" class="operator" value="/" />

<p class="semig">Result is: <span id="resultat">???</span></p>

</body>
</html>
```